# How to mount AWS EFS to Macbook or local computers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I am trying to mount AWS EFS to my local MacBook (also other local computers)
However, it is not working.

My port 22 and 2049 is wide open as a testing.

I tried few command like
`mount -t nfs4 -o nfservers=4.1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ efs/`

But I am keep getting a `connection timed out` error.

Also I tried mounting this EFS to another AWS account EC2 instances.
But keep getting same error.

For example, I have EFS in Account1 and EC2 in Account2 (Different VPC)
and trying:

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/ /efs/
```

It is not working unless I have my EC2 in the same account (which is account1).

Is there a way I can mount this EFS in different account or local computers?

Comment: There's excellent answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/799016/elastic-file-system-efs-mount-outside-of-aws

Comment: Maybe it's worth adding that AWS has recently announced support for mounting EFS volumes external to AWS via DirectConnect.

Comment: @MichalGasek I guess there is no official way as of now? I don't think my company will let me to proxy thing..

Comment: It is officially unsuported. The "proxy thing" is doable on a $5/month t2.nano instance (I have two of them, they work perfectly for this) so I'm not sure why you would have a problem doing that. Assuming you have an existing tunnel or VPC peering and the proxy is inside the VPC, there is no reason for the solution to pose a security risk.  Then again, you didn't actually mention that you had peered the VPCs.  I have not tested whether EFS can cross a peering connection without the proxy, but for sure, traffic can't cross VPC boundaries without one. (Thanks for sharing the link, @MichalGasek).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I will try that as a testing. However, I am almost 100percent sure that our information security team will not allow that at all..

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/on-premises-access-to-amazon-efs-via-aws-direct-connect-available-in-us-east-n-virginia-region/. Access to EFS via direct connect is now officially supported in IAD.

Comment: I recently come up with the following - https://erudinsky.com/2017/08/30/aws-efs-windows. In case of mac you just deal with smb://your-re-exported-share, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 14):

For those who are curious, try

`sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=4,tcp,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 -w host_ip:/ efs`

worked for me via direct connect.

Comment: I am getting `No such file or directory` even though I can `ls` and see that my local path indeed exists.
Do I need to install `amazon-efs-utils`?

Comment: some for me. Are you on mac ? Did try while being connected via Vpn Client Endpoint

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was to mount it to an EC2 ("on-premises"), give myself SSH access to that server, and then use [`sshfs`](https://osxfuse.github.io/) to access it.

```
sshfs -o allow_other,IdentityFile={YOUR_SSH_KEY} {REMOTE_USERNAME}@{YOUR_URL}:/{YOUR}/{FOLDER}/{ON_REMOTE} /{YOUR}/{LOCAL}/{FOLDER}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=4,tcp,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 -w host_ip:/ efs
```

I have tried using the AWS Client connect VPN i.e. P2S VPN. it worked for me as well. With the latest changes now the EFS can be connected from your local machine using AWS VPN.

To access EFS file systems from on-premises, you must have an AWS Direct Connect or AWS VPN connection between your on-premises datacenter and your Amazon VPC.